# google analytics api - Advice on integration with web app

Tags: google-analytics

This is more a question of if this is the right way to achieve the desired solution.
We are building an eCommerce store like Shopify. We want to display report/data to our users for their stores.
Using GA can we do this. We was thinking of using one account. Adding the tracking api. Posting the store sales using the eCommerce plugin.
Then pulling the data back into our control panel, show graphs etc.
Is this a workable solution.
What would the issues be.
Best way to segment for each store so that we don't have data bleed (we may have thousands of stores - coincidentally they would have a domain like mystore.yourstore.com)

Any advice or better ways of us doing this without re-inventing the wheel.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can segment data with a custom Google Analytics variable or by setting the subdomain, e.g.:

```
pageTracker._setDomainName("subdomain.yoursite.com");
```

I think your approach is viable, but the notable challenge is that you have build out custom code to pull all of the data from Google Analytics into your application. I don't know of many off the shelf products that would offer this type of segmentation for analytics without requiring you to manage and create users for every subdomain/store.

The only thing I can think of is building out automated reports in Google Analytics (or similarly in Omniture) and have them sent to your store owners. But unfortunately those would be static reports such as PDFs.